# black screen on boot for more than 30 seconds

Tags: boot

I am on Ubuntu 15.04, I get normal boot animation but after that and before I can see my desktop wallpaper I get black screen for more than 30 seconds. Can someone help me out here?

Comment: They ask this question far better over on Ask Ubuntu, with log dumps and the reports generated by `systemd-analyze blame` and `systemd-analyze critical-chain` included in questions:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/615006/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/614349/  http://askubuntu.com/questions/612600/ http://askubuntu.com/questions/616144/  Examples to follow if you don't want _What happens if you change this setting?_ guesswork answers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried booting with a kernel argument?

At GRUB, press 'e' to edit the grub entry, and add to end of the block of text:

```
nomodeset
```

and then continue to boot.

The string `nomodeset` turns off the kernel mode setting function that sometimes causes problems for some graphic cards.

http://www.x.org/wiki/ModeSetting/

Comment: if I do that then I may not be able to use my nvidia graphics card right?